# Python Mock - How to get the return of a MagicMock as if it was a normal method

Tags: python, unit-testing, mocking, python-unittest, python-mock

For example:

```
import mock

class MyClass(object):
    def foo(self, x, y, z):
        return (x, y, z)


class TestMyClass(TestCase)
    @mock.patch('MyClass')
    def TestMyClass(self, MyClassMock):
        foo_mock = MyClassMock.foo()

        self.assertEquals((x, y, z), foo_mock)
```

So, the real question is: How to get the return of that test intead of getting this `<MagicMock name='MyClass.foo()' id='191728464'>` or how to deal with this MagicMock object to get the return of that test which should be a tuple containing 3 elements and nothing more or less?

Any suggestion, any idea, any argument will be welcome.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are you trying to test if `MyClass.foo()` works correctly? Because then you should *not* mock it.

Comment: No. The idea here in this question is to know how to get the return of that test instead of a MagicMock object, because I would apply this in difference scenarios. There are tests that I need the exactly values in return, not a MagicMock object.

Comment: I've built an example below; one that does mocks something else, but does set the return value.

Comment: If you really meant to mock `MyClass.foo()`, then your example is overly verbose (and incorrect, there is no `self` on `def TestMyClass()`). You are calling the mock directly, in any case, and the original `MyClass.foo()` is *never* called as it has been replaced by the mock.

Comment: There's no need to make explicitly call to a class and nor even instantiate it. The mock library makes everything magically. Somehow, following my example code above, after run the test, the foo_mock will be known only as `<MagicMock name='MyClass.foo()' id='191728464'>`.

Comment: Yes, because you specifically mocked `MyClass`. You replaced the whole class with a mock. Anything you call on a mock, returns another mock unless you specifically set the return value, `MyClassMock.foo.return_value` can be set to something else. But why mock this whole class and then just test the mock?

Comment: Hm, yeah, I got it. That's what I was not understanding. Your last sentence just open my eyes.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you trying to test if `MyClass.foo()` works correctly, you should *not* mock it.

Mocking is used for anything **outside** the code-under-test; if `foo` called another, external function `some_module.bar()`, then you'd mock `some_module.bar()` and give it a staged return value:

```
import some_module

class MyClass(object):
    def foo(self, x, y, z):
        result = some_module.bar(x, y, z)
        return result[0] + 2, result[1] * 2, result[2] - 2

class TestMyClass(TestCase):
    @mock.patch('some_module.bar')
    def test_myclass(self, mocked_bar):
        mocked_bar.return_value = (10, 20, 30)

        mc = MyClass()

        # calling MyClass.foo returns a result based on bar()
        self.assertEquals(mc.foo('spam', 'ham', 'eggs'),
            (12, 40, 28))
        # some_class.bar() was called with the original arguments
        mocked_bar.assert_called_with('spam', 'ham', 'eggs')
```

Here I set `mocked_bar.return_value` to what should be returned when the mocked `some_module.bar()` function is called. When the code-under-test actually calls `bar()`, the mock returns that value.

When you don't set a `return_value` a *new* `MagicMock()` object is returned instead, one that'll support further calls, and you can test for those calls just like on the `mocked_bar` object, etc.